# How do I find out when an application was installed via dnf?

Tags: dnf

I'm a bit miffed my screen shot program suddenly changed on me. I'm not sure what happened. I'm just trying to find out when it was installed.

```
dnf history userinstalled
```

gives me a full list of all installed (for user).

```
dnf history list all
```

gives "No transaction which manipulates package 'all' was found."

I'm looking for the time and date and user and as much data as possible about each entry.

Comment: `rpm -qi` will show the install-time for a given package.

Comment: @ThomasDickey Thanks. Do you want to answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rpm -qi` for a given package shows (among other things) the date/time when a package was installed, e.g.,

```
$ rpm -qi httpd-tools-2.4.43-5.fc32.x86_64
```

on my Fedora 32 machine gives me

```
Name        : httpd-tools
Version     : 2.4.43
Release     : 5.fc32
Architecture: x86_64
Install Date: Thu 16 Jul 2020 03:59:43 PM EDT
Group       : Unspecified
Size        : 209268
License     : ASL 2.0
Signature   : RSA/SHA256, Thu 09 Jul 2020 01:00:07 PM EDT, Key ID 6c13026d12c94>
Source RPM  : httpd-2.4.43-5.fc32.src.rpm
Build Date  : Thu 09 Jul 2020 11:12:20 AM EDT
Build Host  : buildvm-x86-20.iad2.fedoraproject.org
Packager    : Fedora Project
Vendor      : Fedora Project
URL         : https://httpd.apache.org/
Bug URL     : https://bugz.fedoraproject.org/httpd
Summary     : Tools for use with the Apache HTTP Server
Description :
The httpd-tools package contains tools which can be used with
the Apache HTTP Server.
```

All of those values are stored in the rpm database.  The rpm program can be told to print that information, formatted differently, e.g.,

```
$ rpm -q --queryformat '%{name},%{version},%{installtime:date}\n' httpd-tools-2.4.43-5.fc32.x86_64
```

gives me

```
httpd-tools,2.4.43,Thu 16 Jul 2020 03:59:43 PM EDT
```

The manpage needs (a lot of) work; the names can be found from other sources.  One of those mentions the `--last` option, which is mentioned in the manpage:

```
   --last Orders  the package listing by install time such that the latest
          packages are at the top.
```

and applying it to the example:

```
rpm -q --last httpd-tools-2.4.43-5.fc32.x86_64
```

gives me

```
httpd-tools-2.4.43-5.fc32.x86_64              Thu 16 Jul 2020 03:59:43 PM EDT
```

If you want to know about *all* packages, rather than giving the package name, use the `-a` option, e.g.,

```
rpm -qa --last
```

(but it's rather slow).

Comment: time rpm -qa --last 

`real 0m0.226s
user 0m0.198s
sys 0m0.028s`

Comment: `1.15user 0.19system 0:01.25elapsed 107%CPU` (and wall-clock time is higher, of course).

Comment: Even in your case it's not slow at all - just a single second.

Comment: When you run it repeatedly, results are in-memory (and faster).  This morning it was several seconds, and I stopped waiting.

Comment: I showed you the cold boot results.